# Getting Internal Server Error when trying to use Gviz's IdeogramTrack

Tags: r, bioconductor

I posted this on `Bioconductor`'s support page but didn't any answers hence trying here.

I am using the `IdeogramTrack` function of R/Biocondutor package, `Gviz`, from my institution's cluster:

```
IdeogramTrack(genome="mm10",chromosome="chr1")
```

When I try this from the master node it works fine but when I try this from any other node in the cluster which IO's through the master node, it hangs and eventually I get the error message:

> Error: Internal Server Error

I am able to access [enter link description here](http://genome.ucsc.edu) or any other UCSC mirror through these nodes (using `traceroute http://genome.ucsc.edu`), and can successfully download data from other repositories such as `Ensembl`, (e.g., using `getBM`).

Any idea what's wrong?

BTW, any idea which port is `IdeogramTrack` trying to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it sounds like your institution's cluster has issue fetching annotation data from UCSC through `Gviz`. One suggestion I have is to see if you can manually download **mm9 annotation** from UCSC; [here is a good place to start, by chromosome](http://hgdownload.cse.ucsc.edu/goldenPath/mm10/chromosomes/). Alternatively, you may use a Bioconductor annotation package such as [this](http://BSgenome.Mmusculus.UCSC.mm9).

When you have your data.frame with chromosome and chromosomal information (e.g. `mapInfo`), you could take advantage of `GenomicRanges::makeGRangesFromDataFrame` to convert the mm9 annotation to a GRanges object, which allows you to make your own `IdeogramTrack` object. Details on how to make custom `IdeogramTrack` can be found [here](https://support.bioconductor.org/p/78881/).

In general, here is the workflow:

```
library(GenomicRanges)
library(Gviz)

mm9_annot <- read.table(<file or url with annotation>)
mm9_granges <- makeGRangesFromDataFrame(mm9_annot)

# Alternatively, you may use rtracklayer package
# mm9_granges <- rtracklayer::import(<file or url with annotation>)

my_ideo <- IdeogramTrack(genome="mm9_custom", bands=mm9_granges)
```

Hope this helps.